# Is there a way to clip an image using a <div> so that it has rounded corners?

Tags: css, html, rounded-corners

I figure that using a div with CSS rounded corners to clip an image will make a page load faster than using an image clipped in Photoshop, then exported with transparency as PNG-32.

Comment: google CSS3 border radius generator. Oh and btw try looking at your webpage in IE8 after using loads of CSS3:) That's always fun

Comment: Yeah :) Funnier still, IE9 actually supports my div's rounded corners and inner shadow, but not my background gradients! Why does Microsoft even try anymore? It's painful to watch IE die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you make it cross-browser compatible:

```
img {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

The shorthand for the `border-radius` property is:

```
border-radius: top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left;
```

So a value of `10px 30px 10px 30px` would round the top-right and bottom-left corners a lot more then the other two:

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:30px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:30px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px 30px 10px 30px;
border-radius:10px 30px 10px 30px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CSS3` `border-radius` property:

```
img { border-radius:5px; /* specify an appropriate pixel value */ }
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize you could do that. Thanks!